# Weblogic Project migration issue (10.3.6 -> 12cR2)

Tags: java, web-services, weblogic12c, webservice-client, weblogic11g

Weblogic Project migration issue(10.3.6 -> 12cR2)

Hello,

After change Weblogic I start getting errors that below.

```
404 Not Found
Connection: close    
The server has not found anything matching the Request-URI. No indication is given of whether the condition is temporary or permanent.</p><p>If the server does not wish to make this information available to the client, the status code 403 (Forbidden) can be used instead. The 410 (Gone) status code SHOULD be used if the server knows, through some internally configurable mechanism, that an old resource is permanently unavailable and has no forwarding address.
```

I think it looks like RPC library conflict.

My project uses the Weblogic system libraries below.

```
MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/server/lib/api.jar
MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wls-api.jar
MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/webservices.jar (Error Missing File)
MW_HOME/wlserver_10.3/server/lib/wseeclient.jar (Error Missing File)
```

After changing Weblogic 12c, I can't find two libraries in Weblogic system library.
In Weblogic 12C, Can wseeclient.jar be replaced by com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxrpc-client.jar? And can webservices.jar be replaced by lib/weblogic.jar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade those webservices to JAX-WS. WLS webservices 8.1 are removed.

more info: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24497/upgrade_ws.htm#WLUPG334

> "In the 12.1.1 release, the 8.1 WebLogic Web services run time has
> been removed. If you are using 8.1 WebLogic Web services, you need to
> upgrade the 8.1 WebLogic Web service applications to Web service
> stacks available in this release. "